# Best way to retrieve mutiple unique fields in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have the following sample data indexed by elasticsearch:

```
{"ip": "192.168.1.1", "port": "22", "protocol": "TCP", other fields...},
{"ip": "192.168.1.2", "port": "53", "protocol": "UDP", other fields...},
{"ip": "192.168.1.1", "port": "22", "protocol": "TCP", other fields...},
{"ip": "192.168.1.1", "port": "23", "protocol": "TCP", other fields...},
{"ip": "10.1.1.2", "port": "53", "protocol": "UDP", other fields...},
...
```

**I would like to receive all unique (ip,port,protocol).** First, I m using the following query to receive unique "ip"s and I set size to a big number to get all the results:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/logs/access/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
 "query" : { "match_all": {} },
 "facets": {
  "ip": {
   "terms": {"field": "ip", "size": 9999999}
  }
 }
}'
```

I then query for each "ip" to receive list of unique ports e.g.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/logs/access/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{
 "query" : { "match": {"ip": "192.168.1.2"}},
 "facets": {
  "port": {
   "terms": {"field": "port", "size": 9999999}
  }
 }
}'
```

and then querying for each "ip" and "port" to get related the "protocol" field.

I feel this is worth way to achieve this! so, **What could be a best or an optimized way to receive this unique (ip,port,protocol) tuple?**

Comment: I think when indexing you can index one more field which content is a combined value of (ip, port, protocol), eg: `protocol@ip:port`. Then after that you can do facet on this combined field

Comment: It is a good trick. I am thinking to have a separated index containing only unique tuple. I have also found out there are some discussion on adding Aggregation feature to ES 1.0 to end these grouping drama - https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3300